# MS Access - Data in top row appears and disappears when focus on the cell changes.

Tags: excel, ms-access

Its a bit of a weird one but I have a linked table within my database. The table is an excel table with identical field headings and data types and until recently has worked fine however now when I traverse the linked table in Access the data will change every other move, changing from the original row to show data in the row below. Iv had a script output the values of the top row and it displays normally however I cant append this linked table into anything and I assume its this glitch.

Im stumped and would love any ideas as to how this happened and how it can be fixed.

Comment: Please provide at least some information for us on how to replicate this. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This is an unusual post as I've never quite heard of this type issue.  To sanity check things I would suggest that you delete your excel table from the navigation pane in Access - and then relink it.

Comment: Yeah i did an extensive search cant find anything on it, This is a last ditch attempt. Iv linked and re-linked the table and the same error occurred. I even made a new blank database and tried linking that to the excel doc with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So then perhaps I didn't understand, and I am wondering what is meant in your first post by: "The table is an excel table with identical field headings and data types"

A link to excel is a qualified "table" so to speak.  You should be able to double click on it within Access, it opens in data sheet view and you see all the data but you can't write to it.  You can't write back into the excel.

You can query it....

You can append the query results of the excel into a true Access table.